# Sturm Liouville problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

The problem $$-y^{\prime\prime} +(1+x)y=\lambda y, x\in (0,1); y(0)=y(1)=0$$

has a non zero solution

$1$. for all $\lambda$ $<0$

$2$. for all $\lambda$ $\in$ $[0,1]$

$3$. for some $\lambda $ $\in$ $(2, \infty)$

$4$. for a countable number of $\lambda$'s

I know that this i a regular $Sturm-Liouville$ BVP. So there could be a countable no. of eigenfunctions. And the eigen values are simple. So can I reject options $1$ and $2$. I think option $4$ is right with this reason. I have no idea for option $3$

Comment: What is the question? Whether the statements 1-4 are true or false for the given problem? What have you tried? why does there being a countable number remove the possibility that $\lambda < 0$?

Comment: yes,the question is about finding the appropriate answers. for all $\lambda \leq 0$ would yield an uncountable set for $\lambda$. And if we consider this set for $\lambda$, we will have uncountable no. of eigenfunctions. The other things what I tried, I have already mentioned.

Comment: $\lambda <0$ is uncountable? Suppose the eigenvalues were $-1,-2,\dots$ is this uncountable?

Comment: $for$ $all$ is there; there could be other numbers too, like say a proper fraction

Answer (score -1):

3 and 4 are both true. As you say, this is a regular Sturm-Liouville problem, in fact the one-dimensional Schrödinger equation with potential $1+x$ on the interval $[0,1]$ and Dirichlet boundary conditions. Such an operator has a countable number of eigenvalues tending to infinity, which makes 3 and 4 true. 1 and 2 are obviously false, and since $1+x>1$ in the interval (except for at 0), all eigenvalues are $>1$. Thus there is not a single eigenvalue $\le1$. Almost any medium level ODE text should prove all this.